# Finding Ground/Neutral Wire in Switchboard

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, home-automation, wifi

Similar to this [Install TP Link Wifi Switch and problems along with it](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131078/install-tp-link-wifi-switch-and-problems-along-with-it), I was installing another WiFi switch at my place.

However this time when I opened the socket board, I did not find any Green wires, all the switches had suspended green wires which were not connected to any other wire.

I have taken a photo, can someone please help me find out Ground/Neutral pls.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go down and shut off the circuit breaker which powers some of these lights.  **Does it shut off ALL of these lights?**  Also it would be appreciated if you grabbed a Scotchbrite pad (blue would suffice) and cleaned the paint off the wires enough they could be identified.  Also do some "raking" so related wires aren't crossing over and tangling with unrelated wires, not so much a bowl of spaghetti.

Comment: Circuit breaker close all of these lights. though realized, although all these switches are in same panel, they are conteolled by 2 circuit breakers (which was weird).

Comment: **Saw that coming**.  It's not weird at all, it's a very common wiring technique where **switch loops** are concerned.  The general idea is that with your lights on different breakers, they won't *all* go out at once.  We just had [another question where OP had **three** circuits in play](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/145425/47125).  Even if a neutral is present, you can't chance accidentally using one circuit's neutral for another;  so really, all due respect the complications of working in this box maybe above  your skillset-thus-far.

Comment: Ha ha, thanks for tips. And I guess I will take your advice and call an electrician. Wife won't be happy about that as she was already saying that wifi switch to be an additional expense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a neutral in this box.  I say this because neutrals are generally not switched, and as far as I can see every wire in the box is connected to a switch terminal (except the grounds).

The bundle of bare wires twisted together capped with a yellow wire nut are grounds.  Grounds can be bare or green.

This will be a problem.  [the instructions for this device](https://static.tp-link.com/7106506938_HS200(US)_QIG.pdf) state a neutral is required.

There are a couple wiring issues there, bit of a train wreck overall, the two screw terminals on the switch are wrapped the wrong way, counterclockwise rather than clockwise, and the white one in particular looks like it's not too solid.

Comment: I agree. Not a great job. So without White Neutral, I won't have a working WiFi switch. As I guess that's essential. Yellow cap has 2 set of wires, 1 white, 1 bare. May be bare one is ground and white one is neutral ?

Comment: They make WiFi switches that don't require neutral.  However these are helped greatly by using either 1 incandescent, or a calibrated resistor (listed, safe-to-use resistors are sold by better smart-switch companies like Leviton).

Comment: @CodeMonkey, edited the answer to address that question.